# Represent 2D array with a GUI

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, 2d

I'm creating a seating chart generator program through Java, and I was wondering if I could represent a table group as a 2D array and then represent that 2D array with a GUI in a window. Is this possible? If so, how? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can load a browser in you java app in order to use a very nice lib : D3.JS and perform your job.

here is a link to direct graph in d3 : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Take a look a this : [image: d3 JS in action]

official d3 site:  http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 0):

If your seating chart has equal spacing in 1st dimension and equal spacing in the 2nd dimension, an easy solution may be the implementation of the GridLayout class.  A description is shown here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html